# Push local WebRTC stream to a NodeJS server in the cloud

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, websocket, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

I have a task, but I can't seem to get it done.
I've created a very simple WebRTC stream on a Raspberry Pi which will function as a videochat-camera.
With ionic I made a simple mobile application which can display my WebRTC stream when the phone is connected to the same network. This all works.

So right now I have my own local stream which shows on my app.
I now want to be able to broadcast this stream from my phone to a live server, so other people can spectate it.

I know how to create a NodeJS server which deploys my webcam with the 'getUserMedia' function. But I want to 'push' my WebRTC stream to a live server so I can retrieve a public URL for it.

Is there a way to push my local Websocket to a live environment?
I'm using a local RTCPeerConnection to create a MediaStream object

```
this.peerconnection = new RTCPeerConnection(this.peerservers);
    this.peerconnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
      if (event.candidate && event.candidate.candidate) {
        var candidate = {
          sdpMLineIndex: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
          sdpMid: event.candidate.sdpMid,
          candidate: event.candidate.candidate
        };
        var request = {
          what: "addIceCandidate",
          data: JSON.stringify(candidate)
        };
        this.websockets.send(JSON.stringify(request));
      } else {
        console.log("End of candidates.");
      }
    };
```

And to bind the stream object to my HTML Video tag I'm using this

```
onTrack(event) {
    this.remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
  }
```

My stream url is something like: MyLocalIP:port/streams/webrtc
So I want to create a public URL out of it to broadcast it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to push my local Websocket to a live environment?

It's not straightforward because you need more than vanilla webrtc (which is peer-to-peer). What you want is an [SFU](https://webrtcglossary.com/sfu/). Take a look at [mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org/).

To realize why this is needed think about how the webrtc connection is established in your current app. It's a negotiation between *two* parties (facilitated by a signaling server). In order to turn this into a multi-cast setup you will need a proxy of sorts that then establishes separate peer-to-peer connections to all senders and receivers.

Comment: Okay this is clear to me for most part, but I don't know where to start.
Is there any way for you to help me with pushing my ws:// websocket URL forward to a remote server? We can pay for it (don't know if I'm allowed to respond like this here) but I'm desperate to get this done!

Comment: I'm open to talking about that. Can you contact me via email/linkedin? Info in my profile.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with Socket.io & WebRTC, see the [sample here](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/socket.io/#12125730150680791)

```
var offerer = new PeerConnection('http://domain:port', 'message', 'offerer');
offerer.onStreamAdded = function(e) {
   document.body.appendChild(e.mediaElement);
};
var answerer = new PeerConnection('http://domain:port', 'message', 'answerer');
answerer.onStreamAdded = function(e) {
   document.body.appendChild(e.mediaElement);
};
answerer.sendParticipationRequest('offerer');
```